# Slow fill database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

The source sends in my program a large number of rows. When the number of rows such as two thousand per minute for one table, all is saved in the database properly. But if you send two thousand per minute to 200 tables, then there is a delay. Sometimes a big delay, in five minutes. How can I make it so that all the information was entered on time. How to parallelize? Or any other ways out of the situation?

Example:

1. send request
2. get response

Code:

```
void feed_response(int requestId, string copmanyname, string someinformation)
 {
   SQL.sendToSQL(int id, string copmanyname, string someinformation);
 }
```

3. sql.sendtosql

Code:

```
public static void sendToSQL(int id, string copmanyname, string someinformation)
 {
  SqlCommand commandTradeToDb = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo."+ copmanyname.ToUpper() +" (id, someinformation) VALUES (@id, @someinformation)", connection);

  commandTradeToDb.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
  commandTradeToDb.Parameters.Add("@someinformation", someinformation);
 }
```

Code is very simply.

Also i have all time open connection for sql.sendtosql

May be i must in sql.sendtosql add row for datatable and after some period of using sqlbulkcopy to insert the DB?

Comment: Be careful here. The way you have this coded it is vulnerable to sql injection. Would be best to wrap your table name in QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new instance of the command each time your `sendToSQL()`method is called, re-use the same instance and just apply the values to their corresponding parameters.

Also, use the [Prepare()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on the `SqlCommand` object after you defined the available parameters and before calling its `ExecuteNonQuery()` method. This saves a lot of time when you have lots of DB accesses: Calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` implicitly prepares your command if it is not yet prepared in advance by you. This means that if you create a new instance of the command over and over again (like in you code example), the new instances also get prepared over and over again, which has heavy execution costs.

If you instead re-use the same instance that is already prepared you save all those doubled `Prepare()` calls. In a scenario with lots and lots of identical DB commands only with different values you'll be much much faster. Try it out.

Of course, you should not forget to [Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the command object after the work is done.

`SqlBulkCopy` sound like a reasonable idea, too, but I personally do not have experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would be an option for you, but if you've got datasets that large, you might be better off using SSIS and creating an ETL package to load your data, especially if you're doing something like reading a file when you're loading the data.  SSIS can do something like that very efficiently.